# Find the Top 2 values from a table

Tags: sql, h2, derby

Here is the query that I tried: Well if I have items as 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. It should give 4 & 5 but this is returning 2, 3, 4, 5. How do I do it without built-in functions

```
SELECT S.item, max(B.QUANTITY) 
FROM Bucket B, Store S 
WHERE  S.Store_ID = B.Store_ID 
AND QUANTITY >  (SELECT min(QUANTITY) 
                 FROM Store S, Bucket B 
                 WHERE S.Store_ID = B.Store_ID) 
                 GROUP BY S.item
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Promote the use of  explict `JOIN` sintaxis, Aaron Bertrand wrote a nice article [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it.

Comment: Maybe because you're doing: `QUANTITY >  
(SELECT min(QUANTITY)...` this is definitely *not* top value... ;)

Comment: We need more information. Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Comment: Any option other than using QUANTITY > (SELECT min(QUANTITY)??

Comment: You have to define what mean top 2.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select top (2) * from (

SELECT S.item, max(B.QUANTITY) 
FROM Bucket B, Store S 
WHERE  S.Store_ID = B.Store_ID 
AND QUANTITY >  (SELECT min(QUANTITY) 
                 FROM Store S, Bucket B 
                 WHERE S.Store_ID = B.Store_ID) 
                 GROUP BY S.item

) order by [Item] desc
```

You may need to replace [Item] with whatever column contains the "4" and "5" values you're looking for.

Comment: By using built-in function I can do that, But i was trying to do it without them

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Oracle-SQL, you can do this  :

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT S.item, MAX(B.QUANTITY)
          FROM Bucket B, Store S
         WHERE S.Store_ID = B.Store_ID
         GROUP BY S.item
         ORDER BY MAX(B.QUANTITY) DESC)
 WHERE ROWNUM <= 2;
```

edit : added a groupBy, pretty sure it would not work without it !